# Order Table Results By Date Ascending - Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, date

Have tried to find answer elsewhere, without success.   Anybody that would like to correct me, I am certain I am missing something basic - I just can't find what.

I have table 'data' with 11 columns, inc 'from_Date' and to_date'. Results currently being displaying with dates that are furthest away into the future first. I require the results to display as the closest date first (i.e. `ASC/DESC`).

Have attempted `ORDER BY` from_date - no effect. Sample data/on-page' results at [my search](http://www.scotsail.co.uk/search.php) Form Code (for ref)

```
<form action="webdeals.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
  <table width="839" border="0">
    <tr valign="top">
      <td width="83">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="105"><span class="style31">Course Type:</span>
      </td>
      <td width="161">
        <select name="city">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <?php $sql="SELECT * FROM " .$SETTINGS[ "data_table"].
          " GROUP BY city ORDER BY city"; $sql_result=m ysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die (
          'request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql); while ($row=m ysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) { echo
          "<option value='".$row[ "city"]. "'
    ".($row[ "city"]==$_REQUEST[ "city"] ? "selected" : ""). ">".$row[
          "city"]. "</option>"; } ?>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td width="100" class="style27"><span class="style31">From:</span>
      </td>
      <td width="108">
        <input name="from" type="text" id="from" size="10" value="
    <?php echo $_REQUEST   [" from "]; ?>" />
      </td>
      <td width="104">
        <img src="images/calendar_icon_pack.png" width="32" height="32" />
      </td>
      <td width="153">
        <div align="center">
          <input type="image" src="http://www.scotsail.co.uk/images/filter_button.png"
          alt="Refine Results" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td class="style23">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="style31">Price Search:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="
    <?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST[" string "]); ?>" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="to2" class="style31">To:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input name="to" type="text" id="to" size="10" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["
        to "]; ?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="images/calendar_icon_pack.png" width="32" height="32" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <div align="center"><a href="webdeals.php">Reset</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <label for="from" class="style2"></label>
</form>
```

Then:

```
<?php 

if ($_REQUEST[ "string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (full_name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";
}


if ($_REQUEST["city"]<>'') {
    $search_city = " AND city='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"])."'";
}


if ($_REQUEST["from"]  <>'' and $_REQUEST["to"]    <>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE from_date
  >= ' ".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["from"])."' AND to_date
  <='".mysql_real_escape_string     ($_REQUEST["to"])."' ".$search_string.$search_city;
} else
if ($_REQUEST["from "]<>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table "]." WHERE from_date>= ' ".mysql_real_escape_string ($_REQUEST["from"])."'".$search_string.$search_city;
} else
if ($_REQUEST["to"]        <>'') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE to_date
      <='".mysql_real_escape_string    ($_REQUEST["to"])."' ".$search_string.$search_city;
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table "]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_city;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection            ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0)            {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        ?>
```

Apologies if this is a basic problem, but pulling hair out as cannot get it to work.

---

Update:
Thanks @Veger and others for comments.

```
} else { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0 ORDER BY from_date ".$search_string.$search_city;
}
```

Will indeed cause the 'unrefined' results to order by from_date however this breaks the searching on 'city' column/field, and does not work when calling on from_date and to_date. Any ideas on how it should look?

Comment: Just a friendly tip: User prepared statements. It will clean up your sql statements a lot.

Comment: Show the version of your PHP that tries to use `ORDER BY`. How are we supposed to tell what's wrong if you don't show the version with the problem?

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS You totally messed up the PHP formatting :(

Comment: @Barmar Regex failure :|. Fixed it now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have your `$string_string` added after the `ORDER BY` statement, this results in an incorrect SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> 
  WHERE id>0 
  ORDER BY from_date AND (full_name LIKE '%<fullname>%')
```

You need to swap both:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0 ".$search_string.$search_city." ORDER BY from_date";
```

so your query becomes like:

```
    SELECT * FROM <table> 
      WHERE id>0 AND (full_name LIKE '%<fullname>%')
      ORDER BY from_date
```

For more information on `ORDER BY` syntax and statement ordering, check the [mysql `ORDER BY`documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: thanks so much this answer has worked and resolved fully the issue. Thank you again.